# wordpress server error. even when php installed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, digital-ocean

When i open my website which is on digitalocean i get blank page and redirected to wp-admin/install.php which is also blank on checking install.php the code there is 
"Error: PHP is not running
WordPress requires that your web server is running PHP. Your server does not have PHP installed, or PHP is turned off."
Php is installed and turned on see results animalswecare.com/info.php
Have restarted apache server2 ... Earlier error connecting database was coming for which a tutorial on Digitalocean suggested to delete files iblogfile0
iblogfile1
ibdata1
after this error connecting db stopped coming but it started showing blank pages and redirecting to install.php .
Then i ran command mysqlcheck -c -uroot  --all-databases
which showed most wordpress tables missing..

Mysql restarted 200-300 times in last 24 hours ...

```
Error log 
170406  9:52:11 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 170406  9:52:11 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 170406  9:52:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
 InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
 InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
 170406  9:52:12  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
 InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
 InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
 InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
 InnoDB: buffer...
 170406  9:52:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
 170406  9:52:13 InnoDB: 5.5.47 started; log sequence number 11284782850
 170406  9:52:13 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
 170406  9:52:13 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
 170406  9:52:13 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
 170406  9:52:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
 170406  9:52:13 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
 Version: '5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)
 170406  9:53:22 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 170406  9:53:22 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 170406  9:53:22 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
 170406  9:53:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 170406  9:53:22 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 170406  9:53:22 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 170406  9:53:22 [ERROR] Aborting

 170406  9:53:22 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

 170406  9:53:23 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 170406  9:53:23 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 170406  9:53:23 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
 170406  9:53:23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 170406  9:53:23 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
 170406  9:53:23 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 170406  9:53:23 [ERROR] Aborting

 170406  9:53:23 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

 170406  9:54:01 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
 170406  9:54:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
 InnoDB: Error: checksum mismatch in data file ./ibdata1
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
  170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
 170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
170406  9:54:01 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
170406  9:54:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
 170406  9:54:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170406  9:54:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170406  9:54:01 [ERROR] Aborting

 170406  9:54:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170406  9:54:02 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170406  9:54:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
  InnoDB: Error: checksum mismatch in data file ./ibdata1
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: Could not open or create data files.
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: If you tried to add new data files, and it failed here,
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back
 170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not
170406  9:54:02 InnoDB: remove old data files which contain your precious data!
170406  9:54:02 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
170406  9:54:02 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
170406  9:54:02 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
170406  9:54:02 [ERROR] Aborting

 170406  9:54:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

   170406  9:54:03 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
170406  9:54:03 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
 170406  9:54:03 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
```

170406  9:54:03 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
   170406  9:54:03 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
   170406

Comment: Have backup of database and wordpress website and reinstall wordpress may fix the issue or you can also try to turn on https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG If this is happening due to a PHP error, you will be able to see what's going on and fix the error

Comment: Do try and break that up into readable chunks, but also consider that this is not a programming question and is better addressed on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ShashankShah Mysql restarted 200-300 times in last 24 hours . I have old backup which doesn't have new comments

Comment: @user995426 you can merge comments from your database level.

Comment: @ShashankShah database is all gone